# Again with the (67) Donut | Donut

Tags: 3d-view

I was doing Part 2, Level 1 again and the particle add has always only put in 1 white cookie off the side of the donut.  I am getting so many it looks like shaving cream.  I looked up at the user perspective and it changed again, just by opening up that file.  It now says (210) Donut | Donut, I did not do a thing except open the file.  This is what it looked like literally 1 minute ago.  Does anyone know what this is and what damage or confusion it will cause later on?  Andrew Price's says (1). Even worse, this is now in every saved donut.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "...and the particle add has always only put in 1 white cookie off the side of the donut. I am getting so many it looks like shaving cream."? I can't see any shaving cream on your donut. The *(67)* is the current frame of the timeline. Do you see the blue 67 at the bottom of your screenshot and the play/rewind buttons above this? Press the first button *|<* and the frame will be *(1)* again.

Comment: I am not sure what happened to my text, only the jpg shows.  Right under my funny 67 pic is my shaving cream donut.  That tiny thing in the middle is the icing, I have no idea where my donut ran off to.  Changing it to hair bring ups the strands but they are all grouped in the middle of the donut hole.  I have never looked at it that way so that may be normal.  This is the first time the shaving cream has happened.